# Monitoring my web application performance from the client browser

Tags: performance, monitoring

I want to be able to monitor the performance(load time of the entire page, load times of individually downloaded js/cs files , amount of memory used by the browser for the page,etc) of my web application from the perspective of the user(i.e the browser client).
Is there any tool/plugin , that can help me monitor all of these?

Answer (score 2):

[This list](http://www.real-user-monitoring.com/the-complete-list-of-end-user-experience-monitoring-tools/) should serve as a good starting point for you. It is a complete list of end user monitoring tools.

In order to count as an End User Experience Monitoring tool it must be able to track the response times that real users experience when visiting the site – not a robot which is synthetically pinging the site. Specifically I am referring to tools that would enable IT operations to ensure that the real end users of an application or website are experiencing good performance. As I have alluded to in a previous post “speed solves a lot of problems” – claiming that even if your usability is not perfect – if it runs fast – people are less likely to notice.

Answer (score 2):

We built a tool to solve this problem, take a look at [Bucky](http://github.hubspot.com/bucky).

Answer (score 1):

Try [FIDDLER](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [CHARLES](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.yottaa.com (disclaimer: i work here) - it runs real browsers in different locations to monitor your site and record asset level performance data. You can also try Gomez or Keynote Systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out Atatus - https://www.atatus.com/ which offers performance monitoring and error tracking in one place for all your apps.

Disclaimer: I work at Atatus.